# Как распарсить JSON-ответ с переменными ключами?

Tags: json, android-studio, retrofit

На запрос приходит следующий ответ

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Успешный запрос",
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "2018-02-12": [
            36,
            37,
            38,
            39,
            40
        ],
        "2018-02-13": [
            41,
            42,
            43,
            44,
            45
        ]
    }
}
```

То есть данные в ответе приходят с переменными ключами: сегодня эти, завтра будут "2018-02-13" и "2018-02-14", и так каждый день.

Процессинг jsonschema2pojo данных под ключом "data" выдает следующую модель:

```
package NNN.NNNN.NNNNN.model;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Data {

@SerializedName("2018-02-12")
@Expose
private List<Integer> _20180212 = null;
@SerializedName("2018-02-13")
@Expose
private List<Integer> _20180213 = null;

public List<Integer> get20180212() {
    return _20180212;
}

public void set20180212(List<Integer> _20180212) {
    this._20180212 = _20180212;
}

public List<Integer> get20180213() {
    return _20180213;
}

public void set20180213(List<Integer> _20180213) {
    this._20180213 = _20180213;
}

}
```

Понятно, что такая модель уже через день устареет и будет выдавать пустые значения. Подскажите, можно ли такой ответ автоматично распарсивать при помощи библиотеки Retrofit или только вручную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие данные следует читать в Map. В данном случае понадобится Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>>. Прочие данные читайте в поля соответствующих типов. В общем, класс должен выглядеть так:

```
public class Response
{
    private String status, message;
    private int code;
    private Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> data;

    public Response(String status, String message, int code, Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> data)
    {
        this.status=status;
        this.message=message;
        this.code=code;
        this.data=data;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setCode(int code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Обычно информацию на эту тему можно найти в документации, читайте внимательнее.

Comment: То есть нужно написать: @SerializedName("data")
@Expose private Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> data; и в поле data будет автоматически помещена информация? Я надеюсь не нужно вручную ковыряться с JSONObject? И Вы обратили внимание, что data это не просто Map, а ArrayList, состоящий из двух элементов таких Map?

Comment: Не путайте Map и Pair, Map может содержать сколько угодно таких пар.

Comment: Вам спасибо. У меня всё получилось)

Comment: Просто уже встречался с точно такой же проблемой, даже JSON похожий. Это случайно не wargaming?

Comment: нет. этот проект называется  Cintru

Comment: Ясно, желаю удачи)

Answer (score 0):

перебрать ключи объекта, записать их в массив

```
keys = Object.keys(obj)
```